# Yii2 : kartik-v/fileinput trigger upload on selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, yii2, kartik-v

I use YII2 + `/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput` plugin. I need to upload file when user just drop it into upload input. Make it by ajax request. When I set "`showUpload`" option to `false`, and set "`uploadUrl`" with ajax action, no request to server happens on change file event.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'logotype')->widget(FileInput::class, [
    'options'       => [ 'accept' => 'image/*' ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'showCaption' => false,
    'showRemove'  => false,
    'showUpload'  => false,
    'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
    'browseIcon'  => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
    'uploadUrl'=> '/module/controller/action'
],
]); ?>
```

I expect the form to create ajax `POST` on the server with my file in data when user select image and without press "upload" button additionally. Is it possible to make it using this plugin? Or I should write a custom handler `onchange` event? Maybe there is some kind of callback in plugin options.

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`change`](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#change) event to trigger the upload manually when the file is selected and to trigger the ajax upload you should call the [`upload`](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-methods#upload) method.

See the below code

```
$('#input-id').on('change', function(event) {
    $(this).fileinput('upload');
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

For me "filebatchselected" event works.

Originally https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input-ajax-demo/6

```
$("#projectplan-plan_file").on('filebatchselected', function(event) {
    $(this).fileinput('upload');
});
```